# CleanMem tool - to auto-free memory allocated on windows?

Tags: c, windows, memory-management

http://www.pcwintech.com/about-cleanmem

- has anyone used this tool?
- with the simple C program doing malloc and then doing sleep forever on windows I could see memory goes down, if ran cleanmem.

Questions:

- Is this tool giving illusion by moving process memory to system cache? (as using windows api)
- If this is the case when using C, everyone will prefer to run cleanmem, instead doing free  (I don't agree with this, 'mem leak is mem leak' unless you call a free)
- Does any similar tool exist for linux?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This program doesn't actually do anything.  The author knows just enough to be dangerous but doesn't really know how memory works in Windows.  This is probably my favorite line on the page you linked:

> Warning: Memory Terminology in Windows is completely screwed. System Cache could mean something else, perhaps Memory Cache is better? as proof of this confusing way the memory has been labeled in windows, in Windows XP the PF usage in the task manager is actually commit charge, not page file usage

If you really could prevent Windows from writing to the page file, all you could succeed in doing is making programs run out of memory and crash.

The line is also hilarious:

> CleanMem WILL NOT make your system faster. What CleanMem does, again, is help avoid the use of the page file on the hard drive, which is where your slow down comes from. There have been users including my self who have noticed a smoother system. A placebo effect perhaps? Who knows. I do know that CleanMem hurts nothing, and does help, to a point.

**Edit**

One more:

> I think I should also clarify, I am no memory expert.

Comment: Haha. That page is so funny.